# Como pegar diretórios recursivamente?

Tags: php

Como faço pra pegar recursivamente todos os arquivos `*.php`? Com o código abaixo pego todos que estão raiz, mas queria pegar de todos os diretórios.

Tentei usar  [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php), ou usar algumas funções que achei no SOen, [tipo essa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12109100/4734177), mas nada...

```
function getPageFiles()
{
    $directory = '';
    $pages = glob($directory . "*.php");
    //print each file name
    foreach ($pages as $page){
        $row[$page] = $page;
    }
    return $row;
}
```

Comment: Todos os diretórios como assim ? Incluindo os base ?

Comment: @Edilson Os arquivos `.php` que estão no `/` (fora de diretórios, só na `/`) entram na lista, mas os que estão dentro de um diretório não (por exemplo, os arquivos em /view/, ou /model/ não entram na lista, e preciso que entrem...

Comment: *-* ah tá bem, vê se isto ajuda.

Comment: Fiz uma classe para isso, é de uso meio específico, mas dá uma olhada - https://gist.github.com/jonataswalker/3c0c6b26eabb2e36bc90

Comment: @JonatasWalker realmente pareceu bem legal sua classe, parabéns... no meu caso específico não vai dar pra usar nem a sua  nem a solução que @Edilson postou, porque o mini framework que to usando pra autenticação é limitado, e só protege as páginas que estão no `/`, então mesmo conseguindo puxar todos os arquivos pra lista (onde define as permissões), a proteção não funciona... Pra quem tiver interesse, vide a última resposta [deste tópico](http://usercake.com/thread.php?id=359). O sisteminha é super simples e fácil de usar, mas tem essa limitação chata :/...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Olha, este exemplo mostra os ficheiros em subdiretórios em camadas dentro do escopo indicado.

```
<?php

$dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("../");
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    $Regex = new RegexIterator($iterator, '/^.+\.php$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);


    foreach ($Regex as $file) {
        foreach($file as $final){
            echo $final, "<br/>";   
        }
    }

?>
```

No caso, todos os ficheiros `.php` que estiverem nas `pastas/subpastas` do diretório apontado, serão exibidos.

Na própria página do [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.glob.php) costuma a haver exemplos nas notas no final da página. Apesar deste ser um exemplo de lá, adicionei uma linha especifica para fazer o que pretendias. Espero que te seja útil.

Comment: Legal, deu certo. Adaptado no meu código ficou assim: `foreach ($Regex as $file){
  foreach ($file as $final) {
            $row[$final] = $final;
        }
        }
 return $row;`. Valeu mesmo! Abraços.

Comment: É bom saber que encontraste o que querias, boa sorte amigo.